# Can't build Visual Studio Project with MSBuild for Sonarqube

Tags: .net, msbuild, sonarqube

I'm trying to set up Sonarqube for a solution consisting of .NET Framework and Standard projects on Windows Server 2012. I use MSBuild 15.9 from the VS 2017 Build Tools and the newest .NET Core SDK to get the .NET Standard 2.0 support (supposedly). All software pieces are recognized by the OS with their correct version but I still get the error message that I have to use .NET Standard 1.6 or lower when using the Rebuild command.

I already browsed similar questions on this site and applied the answers to those but nothing seems to fix it.

The command is I'm using is:

```
MSBuild.exe /t: Rebuild
```

The Error message is:

> Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(126, 5:)The current
>   .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Standard 2.0. Either target
>   .NET Standard 1.6 or lower, or use a versio of the .NET SDK that
>   supports .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Maybe show us your commands for msbuild and exact error message you get? You are just building your project with MSBuild or you are using SonarScanner.MSBuild?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your solution contains a .NET Core project in version 1.0 which is incompatible with .NET Standard 2.0.

Check this table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: The solution only contains .NET Framework ans Standard Projects. I can build it for example with a .NET Framework SDK Docker image without problem.